# Chrome Extension:determine if it is a synced extension or the original system where it is installed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to determine if the extension got added via sync or is it the primary(original) system where it has first installed the extension? on the synced system we want to disable certain functionality.

Is there a API to determine this ?

Thanks,
Swetha

Comment: There's no API. You can store something in chrome.storage.local and check it.